# JPA cascade persistence with ElementCollection of enums

Tags: jpa, enums

Im trying to cascade persist the following:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

  ...

  @Column(name = "COLUMN_ID")
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "COLLECTION_TABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "JOIN_COLUMN"))
  @Convert(converter = MyEnumConverter.class)
  private Set<MyEnum> enums = new HashSet<>();

  ...
}
```

When making

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
// ... some other setters
entity.getEnums().add(MyEnum.A);
em.persist(entity);
```

I can see several insert statements (for the other `@OneTo*` fields not included in the example), but there is no `insert into COLLECTION_TABLE` issued.

As stated in the [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection):

> There is no cascade option on an ElementCollection, the target objects are always persisted, merged, removed with their parent.

I tried multiple things without success.
Am I doing this right?

Comment: Why do you have an element collection annotation as well as the Column annotation? One or the other should be used - so I suspect this is being treated like a basic mapping. Check that your MyEnumConverter is being fired and that the returned value is going into the "COLUMN_ID" as the collection table annotation is likely just being ignored.

Comment: The converter is not being fired, that is a nice clue. However the `@Column` annotation is needed, check the docs. In fact, entity repository find methods succed in retrieving the collection of enums correctly. Anyways, I removed the `@Column` annotation as proposed but sadly, by doing that my `repository.find` method tests fail.

Comment: While you are correct, its your code, I don't need to check the docs :)  What is in the set after the persist call? What is inserted into your main table, and are you forcing statements with flush or commit on the transaction? What you've shown isn't wrong, but something you haven't shown must be.

Comment: The problem was that the `COLLECTION_TABLE` wasn't really a @CollectionTable and the Enum had to maintain the `@ManyToOne` side of the relationship. Mistake on my side. MyEnum is no longer an enum, it is now an entity and everything is working as intended. Thanks for your comments @Chris